Recaulk a shower door frame
The caulk between a fiberglass shower/tub and a shower door frame is looking kind of icky.
I'm thinking of removing the frame, cleaning it up and re-caulking it.   However, I don't want the problem to re-occur.   What are the ramifications of doing it as illustrated below?   I know some water may sit in the gap but...out of site, out if mind!


You must do it as the instructions said or it may leak. There are specific drainage paths designed into these things. I've seen it first hand. For that reason, there isn't enough information here to answer.

TL;DR: I don’t recommend it.
Some 30 years ago now, my dad decided to do something similar, applying caulk only to the outside edge of the shower door, his reasoning being that if water were to get in there, it would drain into the shower, not on the other side.
Every time when, during cleaning, I directed a jet of water from the shower head at the gap, lots of gunk would come out.
Problem is, the gap still gets wet and the “icky” stuff (molds, limestone and the like) build up in there. It may be out of sight, but not “out of site” and will soon come back to remind you that it’s still there. You’ll eventually end up with more ickiness, as that gap is near-impossible to keep clean.
I recommend the following:

Caulk the inside edge at least – this is what gets exposed to moisture, the outside edge is mostly for looks.
Where you have a horizontal line of caulk at the bottom, make sure water can easily run off (the caulk should not form a groove in which water collects and sits until it dries).
Dry the shower area (including the caulk) after showering – this will reduce the exposure to moisture so it’ll take longer for the problem to recur.
Accept the fact that nothing lasts forever, especially in the home, and you will need to re-caulk eventually – silicone caulk shrinks over time, compromising the seal. The above are measures to make the caulk last longer that it would otherwise, but not indefinitely.


You must do it as the instructions said or it may leak. There are specific drainage paths designed into these things. I've seen it first hand--two identical kits, one caulked outside only didn't leak. One caulked inside did.

+100 for the last point!

@isherwood fair point, though a kit that is not meant to be caulked on the inside, due to the design of the drainage paths, would likely be prone to the gunk-in-the-gap issues I mentioned (note that drained != absolutely dry). I’d stay away from those when buying new. OP apparently has had the kit for a while and would have noticed if there are leaks – if there are none so far, it’s likely OK to caulk on both sides.
